# Create a web browser with tab capability

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I want to recreate a simple browser with tab capability.  A new tab has to be created every time the user clicks on "button_addTab" or when the selected web site tries to open a new window.

Here is my code:

**Add a new tab by pressing the dedicated button:**

```
private void button_addTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage addedTabPage = new TabPage("tab title"); //create the new tab
    tabControl_webBrowsers.TabPages.Add(addedTabPage); //add the tab to the TabControl

    WebBrowser addedWebBrowser = new WebBrowser()
    {
        Parent = addedTabPage, //add the new webBrowser to the new tab
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    }
    addedWebBrowser.Navigate("www.google.com");
```

**Prevent a site from opening new windows** (if you know every webBrowsers name) **:**

```
private void specificWebBrowser_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser thisWebBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    e.Cancel = true;    
    TabPage addedTabPage = new TabPage("tab title");
    tabControl_webBrowsers.TabPages.Add(addedTabPage);
    WebBrowser addedWebBrowser = new WebBrowser()
    {
         Parent = addedTabPage,
         Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    } 
    addedWebBrowser.Navigate(thisWebBrowser.StatusText.ToString());
 }
```

Now my question is: 
How can I modify the second branch of code in order to match all the web browsers created with no names when the first code is called (at one time)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# dynamically add event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531594/c-sharp-dynamically-add-event-handler).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to modify the first function to attach an event handler to newly created browser:

```
private void button_addTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage addedTabPage = new TabPage("tab title"); //create the new tab
            tabControl_webBrowsers.TabPages.Add(addedTabPage); //add the tab to the TabControl

            WebBrowser addedWebBrowser = new WebBrowser()
            {
                Parent = addedTabPage, //add the new webBrowser to the new tab
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };
            addedWebBrowser.NewWindow += specificWebBrowser_NewWindow;
            addedWebBrowser.Navigate("www.google.com");
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it works. As suggested by Nikolay Khil I've looked at the previous asked question, but the statement [ addedWebBrowser.NewWindow += new EventHandler(specificWebBrowser_NewWindow); ] seems to have an error whereas [ addedWebBrowser.NewWindow += specificWebBrowser_NewWindow; ] properly runs (I have only to change function name). Thank you all.