# Add mouse Click Event for dynamically created panels

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i am developing a windows forms application in C#.

I have a FlowLayoutPanel and inside it i have a dynamic list of panels. 
How can i add mouse click events for the panels inside FlowLayoutPanel?

---

Thx for this.But can i call some void function, and not event funtion.Something like this:

```
private void example(String x)
    {
        label2.Text = x;
    }
```

Comment: You could easily call `example()` for an event handler. To handle an event, you must pass a reference to a function of the same [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx). `example()` does not have the correct signature for a click event handler.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```
private void attachClickEventHandler()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     Panel p = new Panel();
     p.Click+=p_Click;
     flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p);
  }

// OR

  foreach(Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
     if(c is Panel)
        c.Click += p_Click;
}

void p_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do click stuff
}
```

Comment: Am I able, by doing this, to get information about the panel that has been clicked? For example I have a label for every panel, I need to get the text in that label when I click on the panel. Is it possible?

Comment: If i corrtectly understand you, you can do that in p-Click. If you want to acceess poperties of the panel who send the click you have to cast the sender to Panel.

Comment: yep. I already solved, thank you anyway

Comment: How can you get the panel object inside the p_Click function

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call a void function and pass any associated with your panel info in it - you can add this info to the Tag property of your panel and call it from the handler function like:

```
void AttachHandlers()
{
    Panel panel1 = new Panel();
    panel1.Tag = "this is first panel";
    panel1.Click += new EventHandler(panel1_Click);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel1);
}

void func_2(string str)
{
    label1.Text = str;
}

void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    func_2(sender.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for each panel as you create them assign the mouseclick with the .MouseClick event

```
myPanel.MouseClick += myMouseClickEventFunction;
```