# Windows form application C# On panel click get the data and show it in text box

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I'm displaying the data of customer in multiple panels, panel with

1. id (label)
2. Name (label)
3. image
   Each customer have a panel with personal details. Now admin once Click any panel the data of that particular panel should pass to the textbox and picture box.

I need how can I make panel clickable and pass panel labels data to textbox.

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047355/add-mouse-click-event-for-dynamically-created-panels

Comment: You should quite probably build a UserControl instead of hosting sparse Controls in a generic container

Comment: How have you implemented, can you post the sample design on what you have done. Agree with @Jimi , you should use UserControl to make it a generic.

Comment: yes i designed with User Control and it solved my issue