# flowlayoutpanel dynamic controls automatic subscribe to eventhandlers

Tags: .net, winforms

I was wondering if there is a more effective way to subscribe to dynamic controls event handlers e.g. mouse click when using flowlayoutpanel with dynamic added controls

I found these little gems as part of the properties on flowlayoutpanel

```
private void FlowLayoutPanelItemButtons_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
}
```

and

```
private void FlowLayoutPanelItemButtons_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Is it possible? would it not make the code cleaner to use these? Would this help with possible memory leaks for example when removing the dynamic control?

I found a working example that looks like this but does not seem to work for some reason

```
private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.Click -= flowLayoutPanel1_ControlClicked;
}
```

**Note**: I actually use vb.net, I just converted to c# for convenience

Comment: What you showed in the third code block is _removing_ the event handler. Did you _add_ it in the first place (under `_ControlAdded`)? If not, you need to do so. Use `e.Control.Click += flowLayoutPanel1_ControlClicked;`. Or if you're using VB: `AddHandler e.Control.Click, AddressOf flowLayoutPanel1_ControlClicked` (and use `RemoveHandler` to remove it).

Comment: Note that you don't have to convert your code to C# in order to ask a question. Just post your VB code and tag your question [vb.net]. There is a good number of VB programmers on SO and also a good number of C# programmers who know VB. As you see from my previous comment, the syntax can be different in certain areas and that could lead to confusion on your part if you're not aware of the differences.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I create an event handler for a programmatically created object in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291461/how-do-i-create-an-event-handler-for-a-programmatically-created-object-in-vb-net) and [C# dynamically add event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1531594/8967612)

Comment: @41686d6564 just used it as an example, so there is no actual code yet

Comment: I am already using something like this:<code> Dim MyButton as New Button()
MyButton.Name = "MyButton"
AddHandler MyButton.Click, Sub(sender2, eventargs2)
                               'code to do stuff
                               'more code to do stuff
                           End Sub
 <code>

Comment: I was just wondering if here is a more efficient way to do the same using FlowLayoutPanel control add and remove event

Comment: If you want to subscribe to events of FLP's child controls that are created at run-time, `ControlAdded` is the way to go (and `ControlRemoved` to unsubscribe, of course).

Comment: Thank you. That is all i wanted to know. Now i will go figure out how to do it :)